# Repeated rows status based on given rule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table like below

```
        RefNo | Amount | ID |  Billed      

        1       20      1      1
        1       20      2      1

        2       10      3      0                    
        2       10      4      0 
        2       10      5      0

        3       30      6      1                          
        3       30      7      0
        3       30      8      1
        3       30      9      0
```

I want Out put like below

```
        RefNo | Amount | ID |  Billed  | Status    

        1       20      1      1        SingleBilled
        1       20      2      1        SingleBilled

        2       10      3      0        SingleUnBilled            
        2       10      4      0        SingleUnBilled
        2       10      5      0        SingleUnBilled

        3       30      6      1        MultipleBilled                  
        3       30      7      0        MultipleBilled
        3       30      8      1        MultipleBilled
        3       30      9      0        MultipleBilled
```

Here Status need to com base on refNo, Billed Flag
Please help me

Comment: We can *help* you indeed: So what are the problems you are facing? What have you tried so far? Are you actually using SQL 2005, 2008, 2008R2 AND 2012? Please update the tags to match your version

Comment: Can you show us any table schema? where is status coming from? a join to another table? or are you expecting to generate it based on some criteria?

Comment: Using Case statement i need to get the output.  
select  RefNo , Amount, ID, Billed, case when Billed = 1 then 'SingleBilled' else 'SingleUnbilled' from VendorRef..... 
like i am trying

Comment: i think need to use Case statement with Group by RefNo..

Comment: What is the criteria for a Status to be 'SingleBilled'? For example, RefNo has to equal 1 and Billed flag has to equal 1? How many statuses will you have? What is the criteria for them?

Comment: 1) in the above case Ref =1 and  Billed = 1  for all Rows then that is the case Single Billed.
2) Ref = 2 here billed = 0 for all Rows then it is Unbilled Case.
3) For Ref= 3 here We have some of them 1, some of them 0 here the case is MultipleBilled

Comment: Some Body Help me Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines based on the info you have given so far... see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/156c1/8

```
SELECT a.RefNo, a.Amount, a.ID, a.Billed, 
CASE 
  WHEN b.Bill_Total = 0 THEN 'SingleUnBilled' 
  WHEN b.Bill_Count > b.Bill_Total THEN 'MultipleBilled' 
  WHEN b.Bill_Count = b.Bill_Total THEN 'SingleBilled'
  ELSE ''
END AS [Status]
FROM test a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT RefNo, 
  COUNT(Billed) AS Bill_Count, 
  SUM(CAST(Billed AS INT)) AS Bill_Total 
  FROM test
  GROUP BY RefNo
) b
ON a.RefNo = b.RefNo
```